# In Azure Data Factory, is it possible to filter the Source query of a Copy Activity, using a column from another Source?

Tags: azure, odbc, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have an invoicing table, 11M rows. I'd like to stop doing full refreshes each day and incrementally load. I essentially want to update changed rows and add new rows.

My idea is to create a table key and use it to determine if an invoice line is present already in my Sink.

Cases: Source Key is...

- In sink: Do nothing
- Not in Sink: Add to Sink

Case: Sink key is...

- Not in Source: Delete

To visualize what i'm going for...

[image]

However, my problem is that my Source and Sink's are not of the same type. Source = ODBC (Hive), Sink = Azure SQL Database. So, in ADF, you cannot join them and the lookup's have a limit of 5000 rows.

Is there any way to go about this? Anyway to use the column of one in the Where clause of another?

Comment: Hi@BriaNicole Powell Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi @BriaNicole Powell, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer. : )

Comment: As an alternative, is there any kind of ModifiedDate column on the source data, such that you only pull modified data from a specified date?

Answer (score 3):

We can use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to achieve that. Merge syntax is as follows:

```sql
MERGE target_table USING source_table
ON merge_condition
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN update_statement
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN insert_statement
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
```

[image]

1. I also created a simple test. My source is emp.csv in my Azure data lake. Sink is my Azure SQL. I create an table and a table type.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EmpType] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [age] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

2. Then I create the stored procedure to update and insert rows. There is a little problem here, azure sql does not seem to support the delete operation after the update operation. So I defined another stored procedure dedicated to delete operations.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmp]

@emp [dbo].[EmpType] READONLY

AS
        MERGE [dbo].[emp] AS target_sqldb

        USING @emp AS source_tblstg

        ON target_sqldb.id = source_tblstg.id 

        WHEN MATCHED THEN

        UPDATE SET

        target_sqldb.name = source_tblstg.name,

        target_sqldb.age = source_tblstg.age
        
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 

        INSERT VALUES (

            source_tblstg.id,

            source_tblstg.name,

            source_tblstg.age
        );

        --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        --DELETE;
```

3. In ADF, we can use `Copy activity1` to copy rows into Azure SQL. Select the stored prcedure and click `Import parameter`.
   [image]
4. Then we can use `Coy activity2` to delete rows from Azure SQL.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteEmp]

@emp [dbo].[EmpType] READONLY

AS
        MERGE [dbo].[emp] AS target_sqldb

        USING @emp AS source_tblstg

        ON target_sqldb.id = source_tblstg.id 
        
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;
```

The same, select the stored prcedure and click `Import parameter`.
[image]

5. My test was successful, deleted no rows in the source, updated and inserted rows in the source.

Comment: Well, sure ... you can code all of that ... or you can use a data flow activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can join them and filter and lookup in ADF. But you're trying to do it all in the Copy activity. This is exactly the kind of use case that the data flow activity was created for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GACpvMjOJgE

Comment: May I ask, can you do this with different source types? When I've attempted to use the Data Flow feature for joins, It greys out the non-Azure connections.

Comment: For data outside of Azure, you must stage it in an Azure storage account first with a Copy activity. Then you can join it inside your data flow.